# Get CPU usage in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

I'm running some [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) tests against a Java process to determine how responsive a web application is under load (500+ users). JMeter will give the response time for each web request, and I've written a script to ping the Tomcat Manager every X seconds which will get me the current size of the JVM heap.

I'd like to collect stats on the server of the % of CPU being used by Tomcat. I tried to do it in a shell script using `ps` like this:

```
PS_RESULTS=`ps -o pcpu,pmem,nlwp -p $PID`
```

...running the command every X seconds and appending the results to a text file. (for anyone wondering, `pmem` = % mem usage and `nlwp` is number of threads)

However I've found that this gives a different definition of "% of CPU Utilization" than I'd like - according to the manpages for ps, `pcpu` is defined as:

> cpu utilization of the process in "##.#" format. It is the CPU time used divided by the time the process has been running (cputime/realtime ratio), expressed as a percentage.

In other words, `pcpu` gives me the % CPU utilization for the process for the *lifetime* of the process.

Since I want to take a sample every X seconds, I'd like to be collecting the CPU utilization of the process at the current time only - similar to what `top` would give me
(CPU utilization of the process since the last update).

How can I collect this from within a shell script?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `top -b` (and other switches if you want different outputs).  It will just dump to stdout instead of jumping into a curses window.

Answer (score 6):

The most useful tool I've found for monitoring a server while performing a test such as JMeter on it is [dstat](http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/dstat/.). It not only gives you a range of stats from the server, it outputs to csv for easy import into a spreadsheet and lets you extend the tool with modules written in Python.

Answer (score 4):

User load: `top -b -n 2 |grep Cpu |tail -n 1 |awk '{print $2}' |sed 's/.[^.]*$//'`
System load: `top -b -n 2 |grep Cpu |tail -n 1 |awk '{print $3}' |sed 's/.[^.]*$//'`
Idle load: `top -b -n 1 |grep Cpu |tail -n 1 |awk '{print $5}' |sed 's/.[^.]*$//'`

Every outcome is a round decimal.

Answer (score 2):

Off the top of my head, I'd use the /proc filesystem view of the system state - Look at *man 5 proc* to see the format of the entry for /proc/PID/stat, which contains total CPU usage information, and use /proc/stat to get global system information. To obtain "current time" usage, you probably really mean "CPU used in the last N seconds"; take two samples a short distance apart to see the current rate of CPU consumption. You can then munge these values into something useful. Really though, this is probably more a Perl/Ruby/Python job than a pure shell script.

You might be able to get the rough data you're after with /proc/PID/status, which gives a Sleep average for the process. Pretty coarse data though.

Answer (score 0):

also use 1 as iteration count, so you will get current snapshot without waiting to get another one in $delay time.

```
top -b -n 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This will not give you a per-process metric, but the [Stress Terminal UI](https://amanusk.github.io/s-tui/) is super useful to know how badly you're punishing your boxes. Add `-c` flag to make it dump the data to a CSV file.

[image]